A certain subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$
Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, so $\mathbb{C}(u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
A monomial $x^iy^j$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ has one of the following forms:

$i$ is even, $j$ is even, "type 1 monomials".
$i$ is even, $j$ is odd, "type 2 monomials".
$i$ is odd, $j$ is even, "type 3 monomials".
$i$ is odd, $j$ is odd, "type 4 monomials".

Let $\delta$ be the following involution on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$:
$\delta: (x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y)$.
Denote the set of symmetric elements w.r.t. $\delta$ by $S_{\delta}$ and the set of
skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\delta$ by $K_{\delta}$.
Therefore, type 1 and type 4 monomials belong to $S_{\delta}$, while
type 2 and type 3 monomials belong to $K_{\delta}$.
Denote $w_{ij}=x^iy^j$.
Assumption: For every monomial $w_{ij}$ of type 2 and of type 3 (the skew-symmetric monomials w.r.t. $\delta$), we have:
$\mathbb{C}(u,v,w_{ij})=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Question: Is it true that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ or $\mathbb{C}(u,v) = \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$?

$\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra of symmetric elements of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ w.r.t. the exchange involution $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$.
Remarks:

For $u=x^2+y^2,v=xy$, $\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2,xy) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$, because $x+y \notin \mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2,xy)$. However, it seems that it does not satisfy the condition that for every monomial $w_{ij}$ of type 2 and of type 3, we have:
$\mathbb{C}(x^2+y^2,xy,w_{ij})=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, take $w_{3,0}=x^3$.

$u=x^3+y, v=x+y^3$ is also not a counterexample, since
$\mathbb{C}(x^3+y,x+y^3,x^9) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, so the assumption does not hold for $w_{9,0}=x^9$.

$u=x^2+x^4, v=y^3+y^5$ also the assumption does not hold for $w_{5,0}=x^5$.


Thank you very much; any help is welcome.
Edit: Perhaps it would be easier to add to the assumption the following monomials of type 1: $w_{2n,0}=x^{2n}$ and $w_{0,2n}=y^{2n}$, for every $n \geq 0$.
Notice that monomials $y^{2n+1}$, $n \geq 0$, are already included in type 2, and monomials $x^{2n+1}$, $n \geq 0$, are already included in type 3.
